# Can I sacrifice consistency to allow concurrent 'insert or update' and read access to a single table with SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains two columns: a resource key, and (very roughly) when it was last accessed.

I have a number of servers that are periodically dumping data about resource accesses to the table. They should either update the access time for a resource key if it already exists, or insert it if it doesn't.

Another server will very rarely generate a report from this table.

I don't require this table to be consistent. I'm okay with the reporting server reading the table in the middle of a dump. If two writing servers try to update the same row, I don't care which gets it's data in.

There are two major questions:

1. Is what I'm looking for even possible with SQL Server?
2. If it is possible, I'm potentially going to have multiple servers racing on their 'insert or update' and resulting in primary key constraint violations. Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2008, right now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm okay with the reporting server reading the table in the middle of a dump.

Look into the `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT ISOLATION` option. This was introduced in SQL Server 2005 and appears to be available across all editions. It is typically better than using the `WITH (NOLOCK)` table hint. For more info, check out:

- [Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb.aspx)
- [Understanding Row Versioning-Based Isolation Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189050.aspx)

> If two writing servers try to update the same row, I don't care which gets it's data in.

It is not possible for two operations to write the same row at the same time. One will wait.

Regarding two trying to INSERT the same value at the same time, since you don't care which one "wins", just trap and discard the error ;-).

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
BEGIN TRY
  UPDATE tbl
  SET    tbl.AccessTime = GETDATE()
  FROM   SchemaName.TableName tbl
  WHERE  tbl.ResourceKey = @ResourceKey;

  IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SchemaName.TableName (ResourceKey, AccessTime)
    VALUES (@ResourceKey, GETDATE());
  END;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF (ERROR_NUMBER() <> 2627) -- 2627 = Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
  BEGIN
    ;THROW;
  END;
END CATCH;
```

---

If you are on SQL Server 2014 (or newer, whenever that happens), then you can look into using:

- the `WITH DELAYED_DURABILITY = ON` option for [COMMIT TRAN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190295.aspx). Look here for more info: [Control Transaction Durability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449490.aspx)
- [In-Memory OLTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133186.aspx) (64 bit, Enterprise Edition only)

Comment: @JackDouglas I have not used MERGE in a highly concurrent situation. Does it two statements issued at the same millisecond?

Comment: No, it's a single statement.

Comment: @Jack But it is not a *single, atomic operation* unless you force it to be so using elevated isolation. Ahd there are worse problems, too. Please read [this post](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). I actually persuade all of our customers to avoid `MERGE` and have even phased it out in a few places where it has been used because of these issues.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for that link. It is both good, and sad, to know that about `MERGE` :(. I can understand each operation being different, hence firing the triggers separately. But not being an atomic operation is quite deceptive and _should_ be indicated in the MSDN in 24pt bold.

Comment: @srutzky Agreed, but they don't sell software by documenting what *doesn't* work. :-)